# How to get only one match in this regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm making a script going through tons of emails looking for two strings.

Either it will find `been all shipped on [timestamp here]` or `shipped by the seller on [timestamp here]`.

Now I get a empty match on `$res[1]` if it only finds the second string, and empty in the `$res[2]` if it only finds the first. How can I fix this so it will always fill `$res[1]` with the timestamp found?

```
if (preg_match("/been all shipped on ([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})|shipped by the seller on ([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/", strip_tags($message), $res)) {

}
```

Comment: Could we get some sample data (snippet of the important part) so we can see if your regex is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to isolate the timestamp and put the rest inside an alternation:

```
"/(?:been all shipped|shipped by the seller) on (\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})/"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/MGYq7RpEqZRWQcfG)

Answer (score 2):

@Akshay2598 has the most appropriate answer for your case.

Another way: you can use the "branch reset" feature:

```
if (preg_match("/(?|been all shipped on ([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})|shipped by the seller on ([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}))/", strip_tags($message), $res)) {
```

}

With this feature , the groups have the same number: `(?|....(..)....|....(..)....)`. That can be useful for more complex cases.